# How to test for OSX on CircleCI?

Tags: python, macos, circleci

I have a Python project I'd like to test on Linux and OSX. I tried first on Travis CI before realising that they don't yet support Python on OSX.

So now I'm trying with Circle CI, but I can't see how to do the equivalent of:

```
os:
  - linux
  - osx
```

Can anyone point to the right part of the documentation for this?

Comment: CircleCI supports different "executor types" including Virtual Machines for MacOS, Windows and Linux: [link](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/executor-types/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to build using OS X you would need to contact CircleCI support at sayhi@circleci.com with your org name. After we enable OS X support for your account you'll need to pick a paid OS X plan and follow the additional instructions we provide on enabling those builds.

As a heads-up we don't provide dual OS X/Linux builds for the same project right now but you can split or clone your project into another repo right now if you need to run tests in both container types.

Comment: Documentation about this can be found here: [link](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/hello-world-macos/)